# Unable to fetch value : JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m creating dynamic rows with two td and text `Host-Address` is dynamically populated from GET request.

```
<tr>
   <td class='hostId'>Host-Address</td>
   <td>
    <input id="btnProv" type='button' onClick="enablePro()" class='btn-success' value="Provision">
   </td></tr>
```

I need to fetch that value using jquery

```
function enablePro(){
 //var ipAddr = $(this).parent().siblings("td").first().text();
 var row = $(this).closest('tr');
 var ipAddr  = row.find('td.hostId').text();
 alert(ipAddr);
 }
```

But i get a empty alert box Please enlight my mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `this` to the function

```
onClick="enablePro(this)" 

function enablePro(elem){

 var row = $(elem).closest('tr');
```

`this` **refers to the window object inside** the function when you bind events inline.

Bind the event using **javascript** instead of **inline events**, then `this` points to the element that triggered the event.

```
$('.btn-success').click(enablePro);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/4Sctn/)**

Comment: Thanks man it worked like a charm but i was not able run using this `$('.btn-success').click(enablePro);` then went back and declared onClick function it worked fine.

Comment: Should work that way.. Bind the event inside DOM ready handler `$(function() { // your code });`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `this` or `this.id` to the function:
`this` **refers to the object** of that control while `this.id` will give you the **id of control**

```
onClick="enablePro(this.id)"

function enablePro("#"+sender){
 var row = $(sender).closest('tr');
 var ipAddr  = row.find('td.hostId').text();
 alert(ipAddr);
 }
```